# Proper way of modelling classes based on database parent and child tables

Tags: java, mysql, oop, model-view-controller, model

I thought it would be best to ask this question from SO community who are more experienced than I am. Since I'm still a student.

I know modelling classes and matching them with the relationships of database tables have a very significant impact on code readability especially when a program or a system continue to grow when it gets added with more and more codes.

Say, I have the entities **Customer**, **Address**, **Order**.

So I see it to have the following **model** classes that will represent the entities.

```
//with getters and setters 
Customer 
Address
Order
```

and

**Data Access Object** `interfaces` may have the following.

```
CustomerDao
List<Customer> getAllCustomers();
Customer getCustomerById(Customer customer);
boolean addCustomer(Customer customer);

AddressDao
List<Address> getAllAddress();
Address getAddressByCustomer(Customer customer);
boolean addAddress(Address address);

OrderDao
List<Order> getOrdersByCustomer(Customer customer);
boolean addOrder(Order order);
```

**Data Access Object Implementation** classes

```
//where I will define the Dao methods.
CustomerDaoImpl implements CustomerDao
AddressDaoImpl implements AddressDao
OrderDaoImpl implements OrderDao
```

I haven't tried programming in Java using the **MVC** pattern but I use **DAO** pattern. So in the example above, the **DAO/DAOImpl** works like a Controller which is responsible in storing and retrieving data from and to database.

In schema perspective, it may have other tables aside from Customer, Address and Order. **Master** tables would be `customer`, `address`, `order` and it may also have join tables such as `customer_address` and `customer_order`.

Should I create **CustomerAddress** and **CustomerOrder** classes in programming Java side?

Also say I want to use the `getCustomerById()` method, is it better to use `Customer` as argument as in `getCustomerById(customer)` instead of `getCustomerById(int customerId);`

I was told that the **model** class represent a row in one of the tables in a database.

I know most of you who are using MVC Frameworks may have a simpler way to generate the codes and associate the classes' model using different IDEs. But what if I am trying to model the classes with matching database tables like from scratch where I use dao?

I'd appreciate any advice. I'm working on a project an some of my ID `getters`, I used the **model** as argument as in `getOrderByCustomerId(Customer customer)` instead of `getOrderByCustomerId(int customerId);`

If you could add the best practices and corrections to how I modelled it, would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't model databases. Databases are a model of data from a problem domain. If you model them, you model a model. What's worse, fatal, really, is you make an object model of a data model. Doubly dangerous, you have no way of knowing that the data model is valid. So, no, don't model databases with classes. Model the problem domain with types and objects. Strangely, it is all right to model the object model with a data model, because really what you do there is build classes and DB both from the domain through a logical model. Do that.

Comment: @LewBloch Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

I won't probably give you a straight answer of how to model this, but imagine situation, when you don't have database at all. What would you do?

When you think of it this way, it helps you to place a boundary between your domain and persisting modules. Without anything persisting, you could use simple HashMap as a memory store.

Then such a HashMap would provide a mapping of customer id to a `Customer`. Having `Customer` gives you her `Address` and her `Order`s. All the details about how exactly `getAddressByCustomer` is implemented are hidden, which would be a good example of encapsulation. Something like

```
public static class Customers {
    private final Map<Integer, Customer> cache;

    public Customers(Map<Integer, Customer> cache) {
        this.cache = cache;
    }

    public Customer findById(Integer id) {
        return cache.get(id);
    }
}

public static class Customer {
    private final Address address;
    private final List<Order> orders;

    public Customer(Address address, List<Order> orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public List<Orders> lastWeekOrders() {
        // I bet real people know what they bought last week...
        return ...;
    }
}

public static class Address {
}

public static class Order {
}
```

So, `Customers` object needs a `Cache` to fulfil its responsibilities and how exactly it does it - his own business. Now, say, you are working with database, then another `Customers` object would be given a reference to some kind of `DataSource` so that it could run SQL against it. Depending on the needs it's possible to cache something forever or for some time, but again - its all internal details, no one cares how it works inside.

When you have something like this, it should become a bit clearer that it's not very important how exactly all of this data should be persisted. It can be a single table, it can be few tables with one-to-one or many-to-many relationships. What's important is that only a single `Customers` object in this example has some knowledge about how to retrieve all this information. I'm not saying I do not care about performance, but that comes afterward. For a known workload we can create specific indexes. If that's slow, we can rearrange data different way to get more speed, may be even denormalise something to get even more speed, but all of that comes after measurements and in any case, whith this design all of those details are going be encapsulated in a single `Customers` entity.

This way you end up having kinda true objects like `Customer`, `Address`, which would know their own names, ages, buildings they live and work, their last orders, etc as oppose to few dumb DTOs, which could only get and set some bunch of characters and numbers without knowing what that is. There is no way to work with DTOs in any other way as directly map them to a bunch of tables.

`Customers` object might look like DAO, but I'd argue it isn't - depends on POV. Hibernate can be used, too, with all its power, laziness, caching, etc. but inside `Customers`, so it is on the right side of the boundary.